# Exponential equation from 2 points and slope

Tags: exponential-function, slope

**Problem:** I am trying to calculate the formula for an exponential equation given $2 $points and the slope, but do not know the formula to do so.

**What I have tried:** With a quick google search, I found out that the formula to find the equation given $2$ points is as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}&\sqrt[x_1-x_2]{\frac{y_1}{y_2}}\\a&=\frac{y_1}{b^{x_1}}\\f(x)& = ab^x\end{aligned}$$

Therefore the full equation would be:
$$f\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{y_1}{\left(\sqrt[x_1-x_2]{\frac{y_1}{y_2}}\right)^{x_1}}\right)\cdot\left(\sqrt[x_1-x_2]{\frac{y_1}{y_2}}\right)^x$$

The problem with this is that it doesn't take into account the slope of the exponential function.



[image]

Above is a simple example where I have 2 exponential functions that both go through the same 2 points yet have different slopes. One of them I created using the formula above and the other one I created using a bit of guess and check.

**Question:** What is the formula to calculate an exponential equation given two points AND the slope.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question to use mathjax notation.

Comment: The slope where? The exponential function has a different slope at each point.

Comment: I would just like to make a steeper or gentler curve that goest through both points, like in the image attached as "example." (sorry I do not know the terminology very well)

Comment: What the information you've already found is telling you is that simply passing through the two specified points *completely determines* the exponential function. You have nothing left to adjust that will allow you to also match a specified slope. If you want the freedom to also meet this slope, then you need to pull from a larger class of functions than just "exponential" (i.e., functions of the form $f(x) = ab^x$ for constants $a, b$). Since we do not know why you need "exponential functions", we can't tell you whether a larger class is possible.

Comment: I see. So for the purple curve in the example, I used a function that looked like $f\left(x\right)=ab^{x}+c$. I assumed that this was an exponential function since the equations looked so similar. I think that I would need a function like that since it would be the only way to change the steepness of the curve while still allowing it to go through 2 predetermined points.

Comment: I found out that I actually needed a bezier curve. This way I could define the 2 points that I wanted the curve to go through and use a third point to modify the steepness of the curve.

Comment: For matching 2 points plus a slope (at any specified point) you need **three** parameters

Comment: Yes, point 1, point 2, and the slope. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\eqalign{
  & y = f(x) = a\,b^{\,x}  = \,b^{\,x + c}  = e^{\,u\,x + d} \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad y' = u\,e^{\,u\,x + d} \quad  \Rightarrow \quad {{y'} \over y} = u\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  \ln y = ux + d \hfill \cr 
  \left( {\ln y} \right)' = {{y'} \over y} = u \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$

So that's  just a linear interpolation in the plane $ x, \ln y$.

Therefore with two free parameters available you cannot have the curve to pass through two given points AND
have there a given slope.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question when searching for the answer myself, so I thought I'd share what I found. I wanted an exponential function to go through two points and have a particular slope at the end point. Let's say the points are $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, with $\frac{dy}{dx}\rvert_{x=x_2}=s$. The functional form I chose is

$y=A e^{-\alpha (x-x_2)} + B$

This gives three equations:

(I) $y_1 = A e^{-\alpha (x_1-x_2)}+B$

(II) $y_2 = A + B$

(III) $s = -\alpha A$

After subtracting (II) from (I) and substituting for $A$ from (III), you get

$(e^{-u}-1)/u + 1/r = 0$, where

$u = \alpha (x_1-x_2)$,   $r=s/m$, and   $m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$

You can solve for $u$ as

$u = W_{-1}(-r e^{-r})+r$, where $W_{-1}$ is the negative real branch of the Lambert $W$ function.

Then $\alpha = \frac{u}{x_1-x_2}$, $A=-s/\alpha$, and $B=y_2-A$.

Hope this helps.

Edit: This assumes that $\alpha>0$ and that $\lvert s \rvert <\lvert m \rvert$, with $s$ and $m$ having the same sign.